# How can I remove a specific node from a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to extract a couple of nodes from a graph to study its robustness. 
I would do it manually, eliminating from the list of connections the ones that include the particular node, but the list es very long.

Comment: If you have a `Graph`, then you could take its `VertexList` and remove the node you want and then apply `Subgraph[g,newVertices]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete nodes using [`VertexDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexDelete.html).